# Geometry Nodes: Dynamic Bounding Boxes for Collection Instances?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I need "dynamic" bounding boxes for Collection instances. I need the changing size of the bounding box in the world while/if the object rotates. This is working well for single Objects, but not for Collection Instances.

How to achieve this, please?

May I have to rotate the collection object points?

See my screenshot:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the answer. I have to realize all collection instances first, before rotating them...

[image]

Comment: Oh, you figured it out. Writing my answer took too long :D

Answer (score 4):

The thing is, Blender treats the geometry from an *Object Info* node differently than the one from a *Collection Info* node - because you can decide if multiple objects in a collection should be manipulated together or separately. The *Object Info* node's *Geometry* output gives a mesh, while the *Collection Info* outputs instances by default.

So to make it work for the *Collection Info* node you have to use a *Realize Instances* node before the *Transform* node:

[image: realize instances on collection]

By the way, if the way the *Transform* on the *Collection Info* node works would have been the desired result, you could achieve that for the *Object Info* node as well if you go the opposite way, make an instance of the object. In this case you comfortably have a checkbox *As Instance* on the node:

[image: object as instance]