# Offseting two geometry node groups by faces or index

Tags: geometry-nodes

Most of the logic I've seen around this have been for collection/objects. I am working on creating an geometry building builder and want to offset the face of one building side (node group) against another. What nodes would work best for something like this?. E.g the left side/part of a building will always be offset by -10m off the x axis relative to the center building's left face node group.

I've also noticed that I have had trouble finding a solution to calculate the total dimensions of a node group. Bounding box seems to calculate on a per-object-inside-of-node basis. Has anyone come across any type of situation like this?

[image: What my geo node setup looks like currently]

Ideally the transform of the middle section x axis will also do something to move the position of the left and right side equally

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I get it right, but I imagine what you call "node group" is labelled "Vertex Groups" in the GUI. If so, you can build a selection mask based on a *Named Attribute* node to flag the nodes assigned to such a vertex group, linked to a *Greater Than* 0 node (by default, the *Weight* is 1). To offset flagged nodes, use the selection as input to a *Set Position* node. To compute the bounding box, use the selection as input to a *Separate Geometry* node with the *Selection* output socket link to the *Bounding Box* node. Feel free to ask for an example.

Comment: An example may be helpful because from my understanding I thought a node group was created when you make a geometry node tree and highlight the selected nodes then finally clicking "CMD + G" to make it a group. Are you saying that in theory it's the same concept as a vertex group?

Comment: My fault, I completely got wrong your approach ! New attempt: you have GN node groups (labelled "RightBuildingNode" and "LeftBuildingNode" in your picture) that are outputting geometries (meshes ?). You would like to know the bounding box of individual geometries, before joining them. So my question: do you use instances inside those node groups? If yes, this could explain why the *Bounding Box* node does not produce the dimension you are expecting.

Comment: @StefLAncien Yep they are instances, some grouped together by collections. I updated my post with what the RightBuilding looks like under the hood

Comment: May I suggest to read this post: [Geometry Nodes: Dynamic Bounding Boxes for Collection Instances?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/292152/geometry-nodes-dynamic-bounding-boxes-for-collection-instances) ?